# Test whether a value is a string in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have a struct that I check for the existence of a key.  I then need to test whether the value for that key is a string.  I didn't spot anything in the Adobe CF docs like an `isString()` function (similar to `isNumeric()`).

Is there a good way other than using the seemingly broader `isSimpleValue()`?

Comment: Go through these [String Functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6a3a) and apply as per your needs

Comment: @AlexBaban good point.  I certainly don't want to return false negatives if the string happens to contain numeric characters or a timestamp or is `"true"` or `"false"`.  It looks like `isSimpleValue` is probably what I want after all.

Comment: Question - what would the pros and cons be of using the `!` operator to simply get the opposite of a function like `isNumeric()` ? It was the first thought I had but I'm sure it's wrong for some reason.

Comment: Is a string as opposed to what?

Comment: @jinglesthula What about using Regex for this?

Comment: What's wrong with isSimpleValue()?  You nee to give us more information regarding exactly what you're trying to test. isSimpleValue() tells you if the value can be represented by a string, i.e. not complex (array, struct, XML, CFC, etc)  If you want to test for specific kinds of strings (numbers, dates, JSON, etc) is the functions built into the language to test for that.

Comment: @BradWood _isSimpleValue() tells you if the value can be represented by a string_ I think is the key.  I think `isSimpleValue` works well for my current case (I've wanted to do string detection in slightly different cases in the past).  After reading all the comments and answers I'd recommend anyone who has the same question read through them all to get a good basis of understanding from which to decide what makes sense in your particular case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The good way will depend on your context. ColdFusion does not use explicit types for variables.

'123456' can be a string and '2016-05-18 13:08:00' can be a string too, you have a good question but testing the value depends on what you're trying to do and what happens next with it.

Comment: I vaguely recall reading about CF and typing being like this at some point but didn't really grok it before posting the question.  In this case, I think "it depends" it's exactly right.  After reading everything here I agree it depends entirely on what you're trying to do.  Hopefully readers with the same question can read the comments and answers here and get the same eureka moment.

Answer (score 4):

Note that this works in CF 2018 only

```
if(getMetadata(<value>).getName() == 'java.lang.String') {
    //<value> is String
}
```

It will be a good idea to create an user defined function `isString` returning `boolean` based on above condition

Comment: isValid("string", 100) also return true. This cannot be a conclusive solution unfortunately.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for pointing out @murphy1310